# Relation between tangent spaces of (un)stable manifolds in Morse theory

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, morse-theory

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808673/explicit-verification-of-signs-in-morse-complex) about signs in the Morse complex, I realised that my confusion is really about how tangent spaces to different (un)stable manifolds are related.  So suppose we have a Morse function $f$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$, satisfying the Morse-Smale condition, with critical points at $x$ and $y$.  Letting $W^s$ and $W^u$ denote stable and unstable manifolds respectively, suppose $W^u(x) \cap W^s(y)$ is non-empty, and pick a component $\gamma$.  I would like to know the following:

1. Can we make sense of the limit of $TW^u(x)$ and $T\gamma$ in $T_yM$?
2. If so, is it true that $\lim_{p \rightarrow y} T_pW^u(x) = T_yW^u(y) \oplus \lim_{p \rightarrow y} T_p\gamma$?

These seem intuitively plausible, and would resolve my sign confusion, so I would be very grateful of either a reference or an explanation of how this works (or not!).

---

**Added later:** A statement of this sort seems to be implicit in Proposition 3.2 of Michael Hutchings's Morse homology notes, but without proof or reference.

Comment: Maybe there this is in an appendix of Schwarz's book on Morse homology. I don't have the book with me.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Just parallel-transport along the gradient flow lines.  You know that $\langle \mathrm{grad}_xf, v\rangle = (df)_x(v)$ for any $v \in T_xM$, and hence the sign of your inner product with the gradient picks out whether you're in the stable or unstable manifolds.  Now recall that the inner product of tangent vectors is preserved under parallel transport.</del>

<del>Maybe you also need that gradient flow lines are geodesics, too.  I'm pretty sure this is true for Morse functions; see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42617/functions-whose-gradient-descent-paths-are-geodesics) and realize that the only bad stuff can happen at critical points (which we don't care about in this setup).</del>

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but parallel transport *what* along gradient flow lines?  It seems unlikely that gradient flow lines should be geodesics, since changing the Morse function without changing the metric changes the gradient flow but not the geodesics.

Comment: Ack, you're right.  But there's a bigger problem - I had wanted to parallel-transport the gradient at a critical point, without realizing that the gradient vanishes.  So we need to take second-order information - some sort of curvature fiddling.  I'll think about this and see if I can repair this horrendous answer (and I'll stop visiting M.SE so early in the morning).